# use image-width in compass helpers in sass file

Tags: css, sass

my problem is i want to use compass helpers and i want to use image-width method . how can i do that? i ran command `compass init` and it made for me some css files and config file.
i think i have to import `compass/helpers` but i cant find it?!!
in this codes i want get real width of image `$bannerOneWidth_pure` nad use it when calculating height in `$bannerOneHeight` variable

```
$bannerOneWidth_pure: image-width("../image/pop-1-2.png");
$bannerOneWidth: 300px;
$bannerOneHeight: calc(#{$bannerOneWidth}*(#{$bannerOneWidth_pure}/560));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@import "compass";
@import "compass/helpers";
```